# How to configure and build VSCode with Omnipascal and Delphi

Tags: omnipascal

I have two problems.
The first is related with dfm form design preview.
Not work. I will try to simulate error message for more info. Before that I need to setup configuration  due to the buld error:"Missig Form Unit".

Let start this amazing post with many different  configuration. All the stuff are referring for Delphi and Omnipascal.

C:\Users\My-PC\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": -0.3862065056838846,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio 2019 Dark",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "projectManager.git.baseFolders": [
    
    ],
    "files.associations": {
        "*.pas": "pascal"
    },
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Courier New', 'Courier New Cyr', Consolas, monospace, '@MS Gothic'",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 200,
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 10,
    
    "GLOBAL": "C:\\gnu\\glo653wb\\share\\gtags\\gtags.conf",
    "global": "C:\\gnu\\glo653wb\\share\\gtags\\gtags.conf",
    "GTAGSCONF": "C:\\gnu\\glo653wb\\share\\gtags\\gtags.conf",
    "GTAGSLABEL": "pygments",

    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "files.encoding": "windows1251",

    "omnipascal.defaultDevelopmentEnvironment":"Delphi",    
    "objectpascal.delphiInstallationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\21.0\\source",
    "omnipascal.delphiInstallationPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\21.0\\source",
    
    "omnipascal.searchPath": "D:\\Borland\\*;$(DELPHI)\\Lib;$(DELPHI)\\Bin;$(DELPHI)\\Imports;$(DELPHI)\\Projects\\Bpl;$(DELPHI)\\Rave5\\Lib;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\F\\Dcu\\D7;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\F\\Source;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FTrial\\LIBD7;D:\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Projects\\Indy10\\Core;D:\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Projects\\Indy10\\Protocols;D:\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Projects\\Indy10\\SuperCore;D:\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Projects\\Indy10\\System;$(DELPHI)\\source\\vcl;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\Rtl;$(DELPHI)\\source\\rtl\\Corba45;$(DELPHI)\\source\\rtl\\Sys;$(DELPHI)\\source\\rtl\\Win;$(DELPHI)\\source\\rtl\\common;$(DELPHI)\\source\\Internet;$(DELPHI)\\source\\clx;$(DELPHI)\\source\\websnap;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\WebMidas;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\Indy;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\IntraWeb;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\Samples;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\Soap;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\ToolsAPI;$(DELPHI)\\Source\\Xml;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\S;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\rial\\LID7;",
    "omnipascal.msbuildPath": "C:\\Users\\-PC\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\\.omnisharp\\1.35.3\\.msbuild\\Current\\Bin\\",
    "omnipascal.createBuildScripts": true,
    "pascal.formatter.enginePath": "D:\\DWN\\prog\\jcf_243_exe\\JCF.exe",
    "pascal.formatter.engineParameters": "D:\\DWN\\prog\\jcf_243_exe\\JCFSettings.cfg",
    "pascal.format.wrapLineLength": 30000,
    "pascal.formatter.engine": "jcf",
    "editor.rulers": [
    
    ],
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,

   
  
}
```

D:\Git\develop.vscode\tasks.json

```
{
  // See https://go.mic.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Delphi",
      "type": "shell",
      "windows": {
        "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\21.0\\bin\\DCC32.EXE"
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
      },
      "args": [
        {
          "value": "D:\\Git\\develop\\Ere\\Eore.dpr",
          "quoting": "escape"
        }
      ],
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "external",
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(.*.(pas|dpr|dpk))\\((\\d+)\\)\\s(Fatal|Error|Warning|Hint):(.*)",
          "file": 1,
          "location": 3,
          "message": 5
        }
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]

}
```

https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-language-pascal#code-navigation

GNU Global 6.5 or higher (http://www.gnu.org/software/global/global.html)

Exuberant Tags 5.5 or higher (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)

Python 2.7 or higher (https://www.python.org/)
Python Pygments (via pip install Pygments)